VSCode Error : sfdx:Authorize an org is failing
I am trying to authorize an org but its failing with this error:
sfdx org:login:web --alias testorg --instance-url https://test.salesforce.com --set-default
    SyntaxError: Named export 'prompts' not found. The requested module 
    '@salesforce/sf-plugins-core' is a CommonJS module, which may not support 
    all module.exports as named exports.
    CommonJS modules can always be imported via the default export, for 
    example using:

    import pkg from '@salesforce/sf-plugins-core';
    const { prompts } = pkg;

Trying to authorize an org.

When you say authorize an org, is it some extension we need to install on vscode? What are the steps to authorize in vscode you followed?

I've just had this issue and I found that disabling the Salesforce Extension Pack, reloading VS Code and then enabling it again caused it to start working again
